# google icon on button make white space

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons but the button with google icon inside produce a white space, if I change the icon (span) using text the circle one will be aligned to another correctly, i think its the span of the google icon but have no idea how to fix it, hope someone can help, thanks in advance

this is html

```
<div className="col-left">
    <Button icon="add" className="mr-8" theme="primary|md" handleClick={()=> alert(1)} label="Create" />
    <Button className="mr-5" theme="primary-transparent|md" handleClick={()=> alert(1)} label="Approve" />
    <Button className="mr-5" theme="primary-transparent|md" handleClick={()=> alert(1)} label="Decline" />
    <Button className="mr-5" theme="primary-transparent|md" handleClick={()=> alert(1)} label="Approve" />
    {/* <span className="separator"></span> */}
    <Button icon="add" className="mr-5" theme="primary-transparent|circle|md" />
</div>
```

this is the scss

```
.btn {
    display: inline-grid;
    border: 0;
    background: red !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    &.btn-md {
        font-size:  22px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    &.btn-sm {
        font-size: 18px;
        span {
            font-size: inherit;
        }

    }
    &.btn-a {
        color: #777;
        background: transparent;
        &:hover {
            background: #e7e6e5;
        }
    }
    &.btn-circle {
        display: inline-grid;
        background: $clr-primary;
        place-items: center;
        &.btn-sm {
            @include circle(40px);
        }
        &.btn-md {
            @include circle(40px);
        }
        span {
            grid-column: 1/2;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
    &.btn-primary {
        background: $clr-primary;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 0px 16px;
        font-size: 13px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    span {
        display: inline-block;
        grid-column: 2/3;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    &.btn-primary-transparent {
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 8px 8px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: $clr-primary;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: #fafafa;
        align-items: center;

    }
}

.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 4px;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
```

[image]

Comment: Use `Font-size:0;` On main div where you are facing issue of white space

Comment: What does the style look for `col-left`?

Comment: @dejan.S nothing, i have no style in that div

Comment: @DaddysCode ive tried to set font size: 0 at the col-left div and in the button but nothing change, i try to set the font-size: 10px  at the icon/span yes its remove the white space but it just too small

Answer (score 0):

You can add css to the parent div. This should work without any other modifications as you have margins set to your buttons. The `display: flex;` (on the parent) will remove the need of using `inline-block` on the buttons.

```
.col-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```